# missing 1 required positional argument error Python 3.6.2

Tags: arguments

Here is my code for part of my program. I am attempting to have users input in order to return an apartment type, deposit, and rent amount. I have included some of my other functions, along with the one giving me the error, for context. I am getting the error:
TypeError: determineRent() missing 1 required positional argument: 'furniture'
I am unsure of what I am missing....thanks for your help.

```
def getType():
    print ("<<<<<Apartment Rental Program>>>>>")
    print("       -----------------------")
    print("      Studio --------> 1")
    print("      One Bedroom ---> 2")
    print("      Two Bedroom ---> 3")
    print("      Exit Program --> 4")
    print()
    global choice
    choice= int(input("Enter the type of apartment you wish to rent (1-3 or 4 to exit the program):"))
    global kind
    if choice== 1:
            kind= 'Studio'
    elif choice== 2:
            kind= 'One-Bedroom'
    elif choice== 3:
            kind= 'Two-Bedroom'
    else:
            print("Thank you for inquiring about our apartments for rent!")
            exit()
    while (choice >4 or choice <1):
        print("Invalid apartment type....must be 1-4!")
        choice= int(input("Enter the type of apartment you wish to rent (1-3 or 4 to exit the program):  "))
    if (choice >=1 and choice <=3):
           furn= input("Do you want the apartment furnished (Y/N)?  ")

    global furniture
    def furniture(furn):
        if furn== 'y':
            furniture= 'Furnished'
        elif furn== 'Y':
            furniture= 'Furnished'
        elif furn== 'n':
            furniture= 'Unfurnished'
        elif furn== 'N':
            furniture= 'Unfurnished'
    return kind, furniture #return to function that called them

#use the apartment type and furniture to determine rent and deposit
def determineRent(kind, furniture):
    global rent
    global deposit
    def deposit(kind):
        if kind == 1:
            deposit= 400
        elif kind == 2:
            deposit= 500
        elif kind == 3:
            deposit= 600
    def rent(furniture):
        if (kind)== 1:
            if furniture== 'Furnished':
                        rent= 750
            elif furniture == 'Unfurnished':
                        rent= 600
        elif (kind) == 2:
            if furniture == 'Furnished':
                        rent= 900
            elif furniture == 'Unfurnished':
                        rent= 750
        elif (kind) == 3:
            if furniture == 'Furnished':
                        rent= 1025
            elif furniture == 'Unfurnished':
                        rent= 925
    return rent, deposit #return to the function that called them

#dislpay the users selections and deposit/rent amount based on selections
def displayRent(kind, furniture, rent, deposit):
    if (choice <=3 or choice >=1):
     print("Description:     ", determineRent(kind),determineRent(furniture))
     print("Deposit:         $",determineRent(deposit))
     print("Rent:            $",determineRent(rent))

main()
```

Comment: In your own interest you should always add language tags. I presume this is python so add "python" AND either "python-3.x" or "python-2.x" (look into tags and see whats available and closest to hwat you use. Else only C++ gals/guys will look at your questions and not answert it.

Comment: Split `determineRent(...)` s funtionality into 2 funcions: one that returns the `rent-amount`  and one that returns the `deposit-amount`. each takes only one parameter (`kind` for `deposit`, `furniture` for `rent`). Use those new functions in `displayRent ()` and see if you can fix it up. If not, try some easier python function tutorials. Deleted my answer because it only addressed part of your codes problems. Splitting `determineRent()`s functionallity to smaller and easier to understand functions as well as cleaning up `displayRent` should help you fix the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your function `determineRent` expects two arguments `kind` and `furniture`. You need to pass them both together while calling the function, this way `determineRent( kind, furniture)` rather than passing each of them individually.

I would suggest you to go through this [basic tutorial on functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_programming/computer_programming_functions.htm) before moving ahead.

Comment: thanks for the edit - you should always add `python` and the specific `python-2.x` or `3` - adding `2.x` and `2.7` is kind of redundent. Most ppl follow  `python`

Comment: main() does exist but I didn't include that, as I stated in my original post I only included SOME of the program.